# How do I set aws_security_token in the ~/.aws/credentials file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have to assume a role before executing a docker container. The container uses the [default] profile only.

I can accomplish this manually by executing `aws sts assume-role` and copying the values into the [default] fields. Then I mount `~/.aws/credentials` into the container when running. The setup inside the container doesn't allow for using the environment variable method without many changes inside the container so I need to stick with editing the credentials file.

Since I repeat this often, I created a script to do this but it fails to set the `aws_security_token` field because `aws configure set aws_security_token` puts it into `~/.aws/config` instead of `~/.aws/credentials`. If it put it in the `~/.aws/credentials` then this would work. How do I set `aws_security_token` in `~/.aws/credentials` so that commands running under the default profile in the container will succeed?

Script draft:

```
profile=${1:-MicroservicesInternal-Learning-Engineer}
myrole_credentials=$(aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::123456789123:role/my-role --role-session-name myname --query "Credentials.[AccessKeyId,SecretAccessKey,SessionToken]" --output text --profile $profile)

aws_access_key_id=$(echo $myrole_credentials | cut -d" " -f1)
aws_secret_access_key=$(echo $myrole_credentials | cut -d" " -f2)
aws_session_token=$(echo $myrole_credentials | cut -d" " -f3)
aws_security_token=$(echo $myrole_credentials | cut -d" " -f3)

echo aws_access_key_id=$aws_access_key_id
echo aws_secret_access_key=$aws_secret_access_key
echo aws_session_token=$aws_session_token
echo aws_security_token=$aws_security_token

aws configure set aws_access_key_id $aws_access_key_id --profile default
aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $aws_secret_access_key --profile default
aws configure set aws_session_token $aws_session_token --profile default
aws configure set aws_security_token $aws_security_token --profile default

aws sts get-caller-identity
```

Example output:

```
aws_access_key_id=key1234
aws_secret_access_key=secret1234
aws_session_token=token1234
aws_security_token=token1234

An error occurred (ExpiredToken) when calling the GetCallerIdentity operation: The security token included in the request is expired
```

Comment: `AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN` is the older (now deprecated) form of `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` and is only supported for backward compatibility purposes.

Comment: Try removing everything that refers to `security_token` from your code.

Comment: That worked, thank you both! I'd give credit if you want to make this an answer.